# how to install lasso > 2.1?

Tags: 16.04

I am trying to configure auth_mellon module on apache.

but I'm getting this error:

```
no package 'lasso' found
```

how can I easily install lasso on ubuntu 16.04?

thanks

Comment: Please stop random postings of the same topic

Comment: what version of ubuntu is this?

Comment: Try this `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-auth-mellon` this is for Ubuntu 16.04